# Using Sass with the command line on a shared Linux server

Tags: linux, command-line, sass, shared-hosting

I am working on a site hosted on a shared server. So therefore I cannot use the `sudo` command.

When I try basic commands like: `sass style.scss:style.css` I get an error: `command not found`.

Is this just not possible on a shared server? I didn't think I would need `sudo` for this. Hosting providers are not being very helpful either.

Comment: Did you verify that the `sass` command actually exists on your server?

Comment: Turns out I needed to make changes to my `.bashrc` file. Fixed it.